# Issue with sympy

Tags: python, math, sympy

Why when I try to get this diff:

[image]

I get not expected result

[image]

The result was meant to be:

[image]

I try `diff(sin(x)**tan(x))` and `simplify` is there any way to get The value I expected Above

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please write a more descriptive title and include your code in your post.

Comment: Are you saying `.simplify()` gave you the desired result? I just tested it and got the equivalent result, except `sec^2` was replaced with with equivalent `1/cos^2`. If so, I am not sure what your question is. When taking the derivative in sympy you should not expect the result to be in its simplest form.

Comment: The "simplest form" is not a well defined concept. I usually prefer `1/cos` to stay as `1/cos` rather than change into `sec`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the form that you expected if you simplify and then rewrite the cos to sec:

```
In [7]: diff(sin(x)**tan(x), x).trigsimp().rewrite(cos, sec)
Out[7]: 
⎛               2       ⎞    tan(x)   
⎝log(sin(x))⋅sec (x) + 1⎠⋅sin      (x)
```

Comment: Thanks it's worked, but I wanna ask if there is any way  if I have expression like that sin(x)+cos(x)+tan(x)+(1/tan(x))+(1/cos(x)) + (1/sin(x)) display as sin(x) + cos(x) + tan(x) + cot(x) + sec(x) + csc(x), and again thanks.

Comment: You can just replace e.g. `(1/tan(x))` with `cot(x)`.

Comment: Ok thanks , it's worked.